# Finding where information is passing in Mean.js

Tags: node.js, meanjs

I'm new to Mean.js, and working with the default Articles CRUD.  After working through the Bossable tutorials I wanted to change the access for editing to multiple users, and now I'm lost.  I wiped everything out and started fresh.  Any change to 'user' seems to block me from doing anything with editing or adding new articles.

<strike>Where is the information passing to so I can make this update?

And can I add multiple authorized users using the same paths?</strike>

Update:

After searching around in the articles.server.controller.js file, if I change:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var article = new Article(req.body);
    article.user = req.user;

    article.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
};
```

to

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var article = new Article(req.body);
    article.founder = req.user;

    article.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(article);
        }
    });
};
```

I have added an 'owner' to the Mongoose file for a User type:

```
owner: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

When I try to display the information it's blank if I use "article.founder.displayName", but if I just use "article.founder" it get a string of numbers and letters.  Playing around more with it I think it's just saving the user._id instead.

How can I get it to give me the object?
How can I pass that object along as if it was user information?
Can I save an array of User objects in my article entity?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the detail from the User.  You can use article.founder(which you have stored the user._id via req.user) to do an application-level join.

```
author = db.users.findOne({_id: article.founder});
```

Then you can access author.displayName.  From here you can use that directly, or choose to extend the article schema to include the author name field(see de-normalisation)

Here is a series of three article I think you will find beneficial to understand my advice above above:
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1